# How do I test code that requires an Environment Variable?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, environment-variables

I have some code that requires an Environment Variable to run correctly. But when I run my unit tests, it bombs out once it reaches that point unless I specifically export the variable in the terminal. I am using Scala and sbt. My code does something like this:

```
class something() {

  val envVar = sys.env("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE")

  println(envVar)

}
```

How can I mock this in my unit tests so that whenever sys.env("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE") is called, it returns a string or something like that?

Comment: I'd wrap retrieving env variables in separate service and mock it when testing

Comment: If you can't wrap existing code, you can change UnmodifiableMap System.getenv() for tests.

Answer (score 20):

If you can't wrap existing code, you can change UnmodifiableMap System.getenv() for tests.

```
def setEnv(key: String, value: String) = {
  val field = System.getenv().getClass.getDeclaredField("m")
  field.setAccessible(true)
  val map = field.get(System.getenv()).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.String]]
  map.put(key, value)
}

setEnv("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE", "TEST_VALUE1")
```

If you need to test console output, you may use separate PrintStream.
You can also implement your own PrintStream.

```
val baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
val ps = new java.io.PrintStream(baos)
Console.withOut(ps)(
  // your test code
  println(sys.env("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"))
)

// Get output and verify
val output: String = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString)
println("Test Output: [%s]".format(output))
assert(output.contains("TEST_VALUE1"))
```

Comment: `setEnv` is useful. Thanks.  In my unit tests, I can call it BEFORE creating my object and verify the new value got picked up.

Comment: *FOLLOWUP*: Hmm. Even though the method claims to work, calling it does not seem to change the environment. Sigh. More research needed.

Comment: you are my god.

Comment: This works great. I added an unSetEnv myself with almost the same code, but `map.remove(key)`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, environment access should be rewritten to retrieve the data in a safe manner.  Either with a default value ...

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("SESSION", "unknown")
res70: String = Lubuntu

scala> scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("SECTION", "unknown")
res71: String = unknown
```

... or as an option ...

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.envOrNone("SESSION")
res72: Option[String] = Some(Lubuntu)

scala> scala.util.Properties.envOrNone("SECTION")
res73: Option[String] = None
```

... or both [see `envOrSome()`].

I don't know of any way to make it look like any/all random env vars are set without actually setting them before running your tests.

Comment: Silently using a fake value ("unknown") instead of throwing an exception doesn't seem safer.

Comment: @stackexchanger, "a safe manner," in this context, simply means: does not throw an exception unless specified in the design. It all  depends on the design requirements. If the design doesn't allow for an agreed upon default (not "fake") value then go with the `Option[]` option.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test it in unit-test.

Just extract it out

```
class F(val param: String) {
  ...
}
```

In your prod code you do

```
new Foo(sys.env("ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the configuration in a contraption which does not expose the implementation, maybe a class ConfigValue

I would put the implementation in a class ConfigValueInEnvVar extends ConfigValue

This allows me to test the code that relies on the ConfigValue without having to set or clear environment variables.

It also allows me to test the base implementation of storing a value in an environment variable as a separate feature.

It also allows me to store the configuration in a database, a file or anything else, without changing my business logic.

I select implementation in the application layer.
I put the environment variable logic in a supporting domain.
I put the business logic and the traits/interfaces in the core domain.